# Get total count from another collection using first collection id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am having two collections.

First one id **pods** having following structure:

```
{
    "_id": "5ae46c0aff1bde1634ad8b3f",
    "admin": "595bdd5aa6ea2811d48a7802",
    "name": "Fashion Trend",
    "datetime": 1524919038771,
    "approval": false,
    "actions": "Comments",
    "description": "Fashion is about dressing according to what's fashionable. Style is more about being yourself.",
    "profilepic": "https://cdn.com/upload/Community_photos/595bdd5aa6ea2811d48a7802_1524919188491.jpg",
    "coverpic": "https://cdn.com/upload/Community_photos/595bdd5aa6ea2811d48a7802_1524919171374.jpg",
    "__v": 0
}
```

second is **pod_members** and structure is as followed:

```
{
    "_id": "5b127683187a4f19901e34b7",
    "__v": 0,
    "pod_id": "5ae470d04e15d607f043a20e",
    "instaid": "5ad9a44cabd2180d64073462",
    "username": "tagtor",
    "user_id": "595bdd5aa6ea2811d48a7802",
    "member_name": "Sagar Dalal",
    "req_date": 1527936643123,
    "datetime": 1527938142745,
    "comments": ["Love the page.    keep up the good job.", "Great job done with this page.", "Fabulous.    ", "Keep up the great job. Well done.  ", "Amazing instagram page.  "]
}
```

I need **total_members** for each **pod** also if pod dose not have any member result should return 0 on behalf.

My Query is like:

```
Pod.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "pod_members",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "pod_id",
            as: "meminfo"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$meminfo" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "meminfo.pod_id",
            total_members: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { $addFields: { "Status": false } }
]).exec(function (err, resp) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else console.log(resp)
})
```

But its not giving me desired result.

I need result Like:

```
[{ _id: 5ae46c0aff1bde1634ad8b3f,
    admin: 595bdd5aa6ea2811d48a7802,
    name: 'Fashion Trend',
    datetime: 1524919038771,
    approval: false,
    actions: 'Comments',
    description: 'Fashion is about dressing according to what\'s fashionable. Style is more about being yourself.',
    profilepic: 'https://cdn.com/upload/Community_photos/595bdd5aa6ea2811d48a7802_1524919188491.jpg',
    coverpic: 'https://cdn.com/upload/Community_photos/595bdd5aa6ea2811d48a7802_1524919171374.jpg',
    __v: 0,
    total_members: 1,
    Status: false }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your aggregation a little bit so you don't need to use `$group` stage. Use `$size` to get the total_members instead of `$sum`. Replace stages after `$lookup` with below stages.

```
{"$addFields":{
  "total_members":{
    "$size":{
      "$filter":{
        "input":"$meminfo",
        "as":"mi",
        "cond":{"$gt":["$$mi.datetime",null]}
      }
    }
  }
}},
{"$project":{"meminfo":0}},
{"$addFields":{"Status":false}}
```

Comment: basically i need only all pod documets having "total_members" field and whoever pod have no member will have `total_members:0`

Comment: Not sure but looks like it is what you get. You get 0 when there is no match else the total members count.

Comment: I am getting array of x no. of object which is total no. of document present in pod_members, i dont want it.  I need only array of 4 object if i have 4 documents in pod collection having `total_members:x` field.

Comment: Updated answer to remove the lookup array document. This should work in 3.4 version.

Comment: That's awesome, now i just need to count only those documents who has `datetime` field exist in `pod_members` collection

Comment: Updated. Please review.